# SQLite multiple table INNER JOIN with USING (...) Errors

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to run a query on a SQLite database that `INNER JOIN`s two additional tables:

```
SELECT
    usages.date AS date,
    usages.data AS data,
    stores.number AS store,
    items.name AS item
FROM usages
INNER JOIN stores USING (store_id)
INNER JOIN items USING (item_id)
```

However, I get the error

```
SQL error: cannot join using column item_id - column not present in both tables
```

I know I can use the explicit `INNER JOIN stores ON usages.store_id = stores.store_id` (and it works), but:
**why does the `USING` query throw an error in SQLite?**

It doesn't on MySQL...

*I should note:

This isn't a problem for me, as I am using the `ON` syntax, but I would like to know why this is happening.*

Comment: You say `INNER JOIN stores ON usages.store_id = stores.store_id` works but that isn't the join the error message is complaining about anyway.

Comment: @Martin: I know. That's what I'm saying. The `ON` syntax works, but the `USING` syntax doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have:

```
INNER JOIN items USING (item_id)
```

...and you get an error that says:

> SQL error: cannot join using column **item_id** - column not present in both tables

That's got to be one of the *least* cryptic error messages I've seen.
What I don't like is that it's not clear to me what table is being compared to `ITEMS.item_id` - is it `STORES` or `USAGES`?  Which is why I refrain from the `USING` or `NATURAL` join syntax...

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, however, I tried adding parentheses around it to clarify: `FROM ((usages INNER JOIN stores USING (store_id)) INNER JOIN items USING (item_id))`, however, that did not work.

Comment: @Austin Hyde: Brackets only work within the ON conditions - they don't give precedence to JOINs.  I'd like to know where the school of thought comes from that throwing brackets at anything in SQL will save the day...  Martin and I tread ilghtly - it's time to be more direct: Abandon the `USING` syntax and fix your query.

Comment: Well, in regards to your "school of thought" comment, I never really *learned* SQL - I've just slowly been assimilating its syntax when I need to do something I haven't done before. In this case, I read about the `ON` syntax and how it was most supported, then about the less-supported-but-still-standard `USING` syntax, and thought I'd give it a go because it is simpler. As soon as it didn't work, I switched to the `ON` syntax with no problems. I was just wondering why `JOIN`ing multiple tables wasn't working with `USING`.